# How can I run multiple unittests in same webdriver firefox session with Page Object Model?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Problem: 1 webdriver session, multiple distinct unittests
Current: 
a) I can run multiple unittests with multiple webdriver sessions (I do not need this)
b) I can run 1 unittests with 1 webdriver session (I do not need this).

Desired:
I should be able to run: 
- multiple unittests
- in 1 webdriver session

What I have so far:
--->>> base_page.py

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, base_url='www.asite.com/'):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.driver = driver
        self.timeout = 10
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def find_element(self, *locator):
         return self.driver.find_element(*locator)               


    def open(self,url):
        url = self.base_url + url
        self.driver.get(url)
```

-----> home_page.py

```
from base_page import Page
# other imports .....
class MainPage(Page):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.locator = HomePageLocator
        super().__init__(driver)


    def method_one(self):      
        self.find_element(*self.locator.object).click()


    def method_two(self):      
        self.find_element(*self.locator.anyther_object).click()
```

----> test_script.py

```
    import unittest
    from selenium import webdriver
    from home_page import *
    # other imports .....
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import xmlrunner

    class TestPages(unittest.TestCase):            

        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.get("https://asite.com/")
            global page
            page = MainPage(self.driver) # HERE IS my problem (2 different webdriver instances)

        def test_method_one(self):                
            action = page.method_one()        
            self.assertEqual("xxx", action_one )


        def test_method_two(self):  
            action = page.method_two()        
            self.assertEqual("xxx", action_two")



        def tearDown(self):
            pass
            self.driver.quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestPages)
        with open('results.xml', 'w') as output:
                xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output=output, verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **play around cookies**. Before closing the current session, make sure you are storing the cookies somewhere

```
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

and then in next instance you can get those cookies and continue.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
for(Cookie cookie : allCookies)
{
    driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried, but to no avail. just some code:                       import pickle
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_17')
element.click()


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
for cookie in pickle.load(open("cookie.pkl", "rb")):
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

Comment: If you are really playing around facebook, please have a look here https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/worst.html#gmail_email_and_facebook_logins. For practice purpose please switch to some other domain.